# A formula to show date range?

Tags: excel

Let me show you a sample data set:

[image]

I used the `=WEEKNUM()` formula to figure out what numbered week it was. Is there a formula to help me find out the ranges that a date follows under?

I gave several examples under the "Range" column to show what I mean.

Comment: So for an input of `3` you want an output of `1-12 to 1-18` (depending on the year), correct?

Comment: That is correct. For an input of `4` for example, I want it to show `1-19 to 1-25`. and for input of `5`, I want it to show `1-26 to 2-1`, etc etc. You don't have to worry about year, assume this is all in 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 =TEXT(A1-(WEEKDAY(A1,1)),"mm/dd/yyyy") & " - " & TEXT(A1-(WEEKDAY(A1,1))+7,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Or if you don't want the year:

```
 =TEXT(A1-(WEEKDAY(A1,1)),"mm-dd") & " - " & TEXT(A1-(WEEKDAY(A1,1))+7,"mm-dd")
```

This is calculating the beginning of the week using the WEEKDAY function. It then uses the same equation and adds 7 to get the end of the week. This only works with a full date that includes the year.

Comment: I was given something very similar. Thanks for the additional explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Given to me by a gentlemen and it works:

```
=TEXT(A1-WEEKDAY(A1,1)+1,"MM/DD")&" to "&TEXT((A1+(7-WEEKDAY(A1,1))),"MM/DD")
```